# Как компилировать в MinGW под X86 и X64?

Tags: c, mingw

Такая ситуация. Как понимаю, 64 разрядный MinGW будет компилировать только под X64. Тогда как 32 разрядный под обе системы.
Подскажите пожалуйста, как компилировать отдельно под каждую платформу X86 и X64, какими компиляторами, и как компилировать одно приложение сразу для 2 платформы?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Как понимаю, 64 разрядный MinGW будет компилировать только под X64. Тогда как 32 разрядный под обе системы.

Нет, не так.

32-битный MinGW собирает 32-битные приложения.
64-битный MinGW собирает 64-битные приложения.

Однако, все (или почти все) 32-битные приложения работают не только на 32 битных системах, но и на 64-битных. Это совершенно нормально.

<sup>(Речь только о Windows, конечно.)</sup>

> как компилировать отдельно под каждую платформу X86 и X64

Вы уже делаете все правильно. Компилируете два раза - на 32-битном MinGW и на 64-битном MinGW.

Comment: Неужели у MinGW нет ключиков для кросскомпиляции?

Comment: @Mikhailo С 32 бит на 64 бита? Вообще, ни разу не видел, чтобы кросс-компиляция включалась ключами. Обычно для этого отдельные сборки компилятора. У MinGW таких, похоже, нет.

Comment: Там два разных исполняемых файла компилятора, 32 и 64 на конце, их и используйте для получения на выходе разных версий сборки.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Ну, я исхожу из того, что у других компиляторов есть возможность даже под другие операционные системы компилировать. Кросскомпиляция - очень распространенное явление, и странно, что у MinGW его нет. Или потому он и Min? :)

Comment: @Mikhailo У MinGW есть кросс-компиляция с linux на windows. С 32 на 64 бита - не видел, но может это и возможно, если компилировать mingw самому и поиграться с флажками.